# Bit shift register vhdl varying size

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to get two outputs (`pulse(0) and pulse(1)`) to deliver a short one clock pulse. The latency between these pulses needs to be controlled by some input value. So 0x1 = 1 clock cycle etc.

At the moment, once the trigger switches on, it stays on

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.ipbus.all;

<...snip>


architecture rtl of trig_latency is

signal ack : std_logic;
signal s_level : unsigned(pulse'range);
signal s_level_d1 : std_logic;
signal bit_shift : std_logic_vector(addr_width downto 0);
signal latency: integer:=5;


begin
latency <= to_integer(unsigned(in_data(addr_width -1 downto 0))) when addr_width > 0 else 0;
    process(clk)
        begin
            if rising_edge(clk) then
                if ipbus_in.ipb_strobe='1' and ipbus_in.ipb_write = '1' then
                    s_level <= s_level + 1;
                    s_level_d1<=s_level(s_level'left);
                              else
                               s_level<=(others=>'0);


                end if;

                bit_shift <= bit_shift(bit_shift'high-1 downto 0) & (s_level(s_level'left) and (not s_level_d1));
                ipbus_out.ipb_rdata <= (others => '0');
                ack <= ipbus_in.ipb_strobe and not ack; 

                pulse(0) <= s_level(s_level'left) and (not s_level_d1);
                pulse(1)<=bit_shift(latency);

            end if;

    end process;

  ipbus_out.ipb_ack <= ack;
  ipbus_out.ipb_err <= '0';

end rtl;
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491507/using-for-loop-in-vhdl-with-a-variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just shift your bits the whole way and ignore the fact that they go above `N`.  The usual VHDL shifter uses the `&` to concatenate the shifted register with the new value:

```
bit_shift <= bit_shift(bit_shift'high-1 downto 0) & s_level;
```

That should produce your shift register just fine.

The `pulse(1) <= bit_shift(N)` ought to work fine.

Comment: This worked for the example I gave but it breaks when I change this code to make sure it is giving a single pulse and not two.

Comment: Can you show some waveforms?  What is in_data doing for example?

Comment: In_data literally just stays at a value such as 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. I know it works as I've used this a bunch of times. Unfortunately it'll be difficult for me to get the waveforms up for various reasons.

It basically shows the first trigger firing, staying on, then a few clock cycles later, the second trigger fires and stays on. I suspect it has something to do with the logic in the bit shift register

Comment: Even if I remove the "in_data" and have that number as a constant, it still keept the pulse logic high.

So what I actually needed was:

else
s_level<=(others=>'0');

Comment: This is why waveforms would have helped - I thought your problem was getting the right latency.  I missed your update saying the second trigger was staying on!