# VHDL- vector slicing

Tags: vhdl

I have input std_logic_vector of (0 to X).
Range of x is 0 to 1000 bytes and the code should support any value of X.
I would like to slice the input into 128 bit blocks, for further processing and operations.
a) how can it be done? 
b) is there a way to make the following pseudo-code work? so i can adopt it for solving a)?
i need to use the loop index for naming the signals but i guess its not possible with VHDL (?)

```
for i in 0 to N loop

  block_i <= input (X, X-127);

end loop;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1000 bytes does not divide by 128 bits evenly

Comment: True. 
In another part of my code, i have fixed this issue. i have this "not evenly dividable" issue under control! 
For the sake of simplicity, imagine numbers than can be divided by 128 evenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity slicer is
  generic(X : natural:=1000);
  port (input : in std_logic_vector(X*128-1 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture rtl of slicer is
  type block_type is array(0 to X-1) of std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);
  signal blocks : block_type;
begin

slicing:for i in 0 to X-1 generate
            blocks(i) <= input(128*(i+1)-1 downto 128*i);
        end generate;

end rtl;
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing, as in the question, `X` was the upper range of the input, not the name of the input itself. The block array range and the loop range, therefore, should be 0 to X/128-1, I think.

Comment: In my solution, X is just the number of 128-bits chunks.

Comment: Thank you so much, i really appreciate your help.
you answer was very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. As a new user, please validate my answer, if it is the one you prefer. That is the rule of game on stack overflow !

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options with how to accomplish this. One is to use the flattened 1-D array that is selectively sliced as demonstrated by @JCLL. Another option is to create a new type that is an array of an array.

```vhdl
subtype word is std_logic_vector(127 downto 0); -- Constrained subtype
type word_vec is array(natural range <>) of word; -- New unconstrained type
...

entity foo is
    port (
        X : in word_vec -- Get our constraint when instantiated
    );
end entity;

...

for i in X'range loop
    blocks(i) <= X(i);
end loop;
```

This solution skips the arithmetic needed for the 1-D slicing but is limited by the need for a constrained type for the elements of word_vec. This last limitation is lifted in VHDL-2008 where you can do the following:

```vhdl
-- Both unconstrained arrays
type word_vec is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;
```

The best solution depends on what your task is and how much flexibility you need for size changes in the future.

A final less appealing option is to use a 2-D array but that gets ugly when you need more than bitwise access.

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful information, i used @JCLL's approach but i combined it with "unconstrained new type" that you mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can assign parts of a large logic vector to another smaller vector. I'm not sure about your specific implementation (you did not provide the signal types and sizes -- is the large vector 1000 bytes or 1000 bits?). However, If you know what X is at time of synthesis, use generics, like

```
entity foo is
    generic(X : Natural);
    port(input: in std_logic_vector(X-1 downto 0); 
         block_i: out std_logic_vector(127 downto 0));

end entity;
```

Otherwise you just need to pass in a size as well:

```
entity foo is
    port(input: in std_logic_vector(X-1 downto 0);
         block_i: out std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);
         X    : in Natural);
    end entity;
```

And then use the size when you are assigning parts to block_i.

Note that you will need to either use the generic or a hard-coded constant (ie: 1000 for the worse case) for the loop. VHDL does not like variable loop ranges. You can work around this, but I usually don't need to (see: [Using FOR loop in VHDL with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491507/using-for-loop-in-vhdl-with-a-variable))